# AWS authorization failed - Solutions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there a simple way to determine the missing authorization from a CloudWatch log? I have the requestId can I find out what was missing? Thanks!

```
    "errorType": "Forbidden",
    "errorMessage": "AWS authorization failed",
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "AWS authorization failed",
    "time": "2021-09-28T07:52:25.809Z",
    "requestId": "7f09cdeb-cd2c-4c47-b6eb-ae1ed3bf8aca",
    "statusCode": 403,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 13.803204907216827,
    "stack": [
        "Forbidden: AWS authorization failed"
```

Comment: i second that. facing the same error and i have no idea what is causing that. We badly need more info on it